# SQL: row to column data

Tags: sql-server-2012, pivot-table

Suppose I have the following:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Dependents') is not null
    drop table #Dependents

create table #Dependents
(EmpNo varchar(12), DepID varchar(12), Relation varchar(12));
go

if object_id('tempdb..#Dep_Benefits') is not null
    drop table #Dep_Benefits

create table #Dep_Benefits
(DepID varchar(12), PlanCode varchar(12), Coverage varchar(25));
go


INSERT INTO #Dependents VALUES('001', '111', 'SON');
INSERT INTO #Dependents VALUES('001', '222', 'SON');
INSERT INTO #Dependents VALUES('001', '333', 'DAUGHTER');
INSERT INTO #Dependents VALUES('002', '666', 'SON');
INSERT INTO #Dependents VALUES('002', '777', 'DAUGHTER');

INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('111', 'AAAA', 'MEDICAL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('111', 'BBBB', 'DENTAL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('111', 'CCCC', 'VISION');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('111', 'DDDD', 'DISABL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('222', 'AAAA', 'MEDICAL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('222', 'BBBB', 'DENTAL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('222', 'CCCC', 'VISION');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('333', 'AAAA', 'MEDICAL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('333', 'BBBB', 'DENTAL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('666', 'AAAA', 'MEDICAL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('666', 'BBBB', 'DENTAL');
INSERT INTO #Dep_Benefits VALUES('666', 'CCCC', 'VISION');


SELECT * FROM #Dependents;
SELECT * FROM #Dep_Benefits;
```

How can I get the output of this to be like:

```
Employee   | Dependent  | Plan 1   | Plan 2   | Plan 3   
001          111          AAAA       BBBB       DDDD
001          222          AAAA       BBBB       CCCC
001          333          AAAA       BBBB       
002          666          AAAA       BBBB       CCCC
```

I am only concerned with 3 plans, even if there are more assigned to a dependent.  This is a fixed request from a client (only 3 plans) so please no comments on why this might be a bad idea :)  I have already told them that there is no guarantee what 3 plans might be returned if a dependent has more than 3.

I have looked at a pivot table but just can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `row_number()` to number the plans, and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    d.empno
  , d.depid
  , Plan_1 = max(case when rn = 1 then PlanCode end)
  , Plan_2 = max(case when rn = 2 then PlanCode end)
  , Plan_3 = max(case when rn = 3 then PlanCode end)
  , Plan_4 = max(case when rn = 4 then PlanCode end)
from (
  select d.empNo, db.*
    , rn = row_number() over(partition by db.depid order by plancode)
  from #Dependents d
  inner join #Dep_Benefits db
    on d.depid = db.depid
  ) d
group by d.empno, d.depid
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FNLH5237

returns:

```
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| empno | depid | Plan_1 | Plan_2 | Plan_3 | Plan_4 |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   001 |   111 | AAAA   | BBBB   | CCCC   | DDDD   |
|   001 |   222 | AAAA   | BBBB   | CCCC   | NULL   |
|   001 |   333 | AAAA   | BBBB   | NULL   | NULL   |
|   002 |   666 | AAAA   | BBBB   | CCCC   | NULL   |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

---

pivoting the plans by type using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    d.empno
  , d.depid
  , Medical    = max(case when db.Coverage = 'Medical' then PlanCode end)
  , Dental     = max(case when db.Coverage = 'Dental' then PlanCode end)
  , Vision     = max(case when db.Coverage = 'Vision' then PlanCode end)
  , Disability = max(case when db.Coverage = 'disabl' then PlanCode end)
from #Dependents d
  inner join #Dep_Benefits db
    on d.depid = db.depid
group by d.empno, d.depid
```

returns:

```
+-------+-------+---------+--------+--------+------------+
| empno | depid | Medical | Dental | Vision | Disability |
+-------+-------+---------+--------+--------+------------+
|   001 |   111 | AAAA    | BBBB   | CCCC   | DDDD       |
|   001 |   222 | AAAA    | BBBB   | CCCC   | NULL       |
|   001 |   333 | AAAA    | BBBB   | NULL   | NULL       |
|   002 |   666 | AAAA    | BBBB   | CCCC   | NULL       |
+-------+-------+---------+--------+--------+------------+
```